# How many sum terms for specific accuracy of approximation?

Tags: c#, algorithm

Find *N* so that two consecutive values of:

[image]

are smaller than 10^{-4}.

In other words, how many terms do we need to approximate the above series up to the given number.

Here is the code in which I subtract two consecutive values of the sum and compare the result to the needed precision as an accuracy test:

```
using System;

namespace ProgrammingBasics 
{
    class ApproximationAccuracy
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            double eps = 10e-4;
            Console.WriteLine("Precision: {0}, Needed terms: {1}",
                              eps, numberOfTermsForGivenPrecision(eps));
        }
        //------------------------------------------------------------------ 

        static long numberOfTermsForGivenPrecision(double epsilon)
        {
            double lastSum = 0, currentSum = 0;
            long term = 0, iterations = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                // \sum \frac{1}{e^n}
                currentSum += (1.0 / Math.Pow(Math.E, term++));

                if (Math.Abs(currentSum - lastSum) < epsilon)
                {
                    break;
                }
                lastSum = currentSum;
                ++iterations;
            }
            return iterations;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> Precision: 0.001, Needed terms: 7

It seems to me that the terms are too few for that accuracy, is the above code and logic right?

Comment: `10e-4` means "10 times 10^-4", namely 10^-3.  I think you meant to write `1e-4`.  Also while it doesn't hurt to do the subtraction (unless the difference is much smaller than either original number, which can lead to catastrophic loss of precision with FP numbers), the difference between the current partial sum and the last one is simply 1/e^n here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fast way:

e<sup>-n</sup> < 10<sup>-4</sup>
-n < ln(10<sup>-4</sup>)
-n < -4 * ln(10)
n > 4 * ln(10) ~= 9.21
n = 10
for 0.001 = 10<sup>-3</sup>:   n=7

Answer (score 1):

Saying that a partial sum's difference than the next one is smaller than x is not necessarily the same as saying that the partial sum's difference than the series' sum is less than x. There are still infinite number of terms that separate the two.

All you need to do is to calculate a term that will be smaller than x and the n that generates this term will be your answer, as that will be the difference between two consecutive partial sums.

In your case,

1/(e^n) < 1/(10^4)

e^n > 10^4

n > ln(10^4)=9.2103...

and the smallest n satisfying this will be your n (10).

As to your code - from the output we can see there's a problem, as 1/(e^7)=0.0009 > 0.0001=1/(10^4). 
We can also see where the problem lies as, although you asked for 10^(-4) you got in the output: 0.001=10^(-3). It's to do with the definition of eps.